# __init__ not called when Cythoning a Kivy App

Tags: python, kivy, cython

So I've Cythoned my Kivy App and got some strange behaviour. Any class defined in pure KV works, any class defined in pure python works. However any class using a hybrid of the two will not call the python **init** method. As seen in the below example, init of MyButton has not been called.

Running on MacOS, I've compiled with command "kivy compile.py build_ext --inplace" and run main.py with "kivy main.py".

test.py

```py
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''

<MyButton@Button>:
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
    text: 'Has init been called?'

<AParent@FloatLayout>:
    MyButton
''')

class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('Init called in MyButton!')
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class AParent(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('Init called in AParent!')
        super(AParent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AParent()
```

compile.py

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('test.py',  ['test.py']),
]
setup(
    name = 'test',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

main.py

```py
from test import TestApp

TestApp().run()
```

Have I missed something or is the best result to perhaps write it in pure python. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<AParent@FloatLayout>:
```

This is syntax for a dynamic kv class declaration, which does not expect a corresponding python class. Use `<AParent>` instead.

I'm not clear on whether your cython stuff is important. With the code as-is, is the cython-compiled version ever used at all?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Use what instead sorry? And yeah I think your right, what should be the appropriate main.py to execute the cython file. This is my first time dabbling with cython.. Thanks!!

Comment: The first argument to `Extension` is the module target path, so your code creates a file called `py.xxx.so` in a folder named `test` (with xxx replaced by something). Change it to `Extension('ctest', ['test.py'])` then do `from ctest import TestApp` in your main.py.

Comment: I think it will use a .so file in preference to a .py file, so the Cython compiled version probably will be used